# Search and merge multiple files in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have multiple .dat files, which i will get to know dynamically. dat file will have two columns seperated by comma. Will be like key value pairs. For example:

```
File1:                
entry1,100             
entry2,200            
entry3,300

File2:                    
entry1,500                 
entry3,750
```

Now I want the output as

```
File3:           
entry1,100,500                 
entry2,200                
entry3,300,750
```

Comment: `join` shell command will do that work for you: http://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to include unpairable lines from both files - such as `entry2,200` from `File2` the following command should work:

```
join -t, -a1 -a2 file1 file2
```

`-t,` instructs join to use comma as a delimiter, `-a1 -a2` instructs join to include unpairable lines from each file.

Comment: Note that `join` requires the files to be sorted on their join fields (in this case the first)

Comment: if i have to pass the files dynamically..like file1 and file 2 ..is that possible ??

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If your names are `file1` and `file2` invoke the command as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk when input files are not already sorted:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0 (($1 in a)?OFS a[$1]:"")}' f2.dat f1.dat
entry1,100,500
entry2,200
entry3,300,750
```